# Android build environment

Tags: android, linux, build, makefile

I have been working with standard android for some time. Recently I have been building android sdk for windows and find some interesting things in Android build env. There is a command called lunch which can be used to list all available targets to build. However, it does not list sdk and its variants,even though they are valid options. 
Does anyone know why is that the case?

Also can I build any specific module in Android sdk without building the whole sdk. (It could be a great help as I dont wanna build the whole sdk, if I gonna do a small change in one component.)

Thanks

Comment: I thought lunch was old, but maybe not.  My old team used to use it to build the entire Android tree.  There are other ways to build the entire tree, or just components within the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, lunch uses make, so if some pieces of SDK do not change, they won't be rebuilt.

My speculation about your first question: rebuilding SDK was never considered a major task of lunch. It is most often used to port or mod the system and produce an installable system image, and receive the ADK as by-product. Later, people realized that often (with root access to the device) you can iterate over one component without need to reinstall the whole system image.